# is there an industry standard width for a screen to be considered mobile?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frontend

Currently, my app has 2 screen modes, desktop and mobile. The cut off for mobile is `725px`.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: What do u want to do? If you are designing a layout it's better to use dp instead of px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off-  don't think of things in terms of px.  Because screens have different pixel densities densities.  Back on the first android device, 160 pixels was 1 inch.  Now its less than 1/2 inch on any decent phone, and less than 1/3 of an inch on a top end one.  Screens are just that much better now.  Instead, think of things in terms of physical size.  The most common unit used on Android for that is dp, which is 1/160th of an inch.

The next thing to think about is orientation.  A device can be portrait or landscape, and it will have different sizes in each.  The general way you tell tablets vs phones is by how wide the shortest width is.  A good rule of thumb is that a 7 inch tablet is about 600dp shortest width, and a 10 inch tablet is 720.  Although that can vary a bit-  the difference between a phone and a tablet is really marketing.  (BTW, the reason why these aren't just 160x7 and 160x10 is because a 7 inch screen means a 7 inch length to the diagonal, not either side).

I'd take that concept and extend it to "desktop" vs "mobile".  Decide what the smallest device you would consider a desktop is.  See how many dp it is in shortest width (you can get that by multiplying the shorter of its screen dimensions by 160, then rounding down to a nice round number, you can find the size online usually).  Make that your cutoff.